# Magento 2: Order Items in New Order Email not showing

Tags: php, magento2.2

When I get new order email after successful checkout, there is no information about order items. Need your help.

[image: Email Screenshot]

**order_new.phtml**

```php
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
            {{var myvar8 |raw}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="method-info">
            <p>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</p>
            {{var payment_html|raw}}
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: have you found any solution.

Answer (score 6):

On Magento 2.4.4 and above, go to the Email template page, find and replace:

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}

to

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}

Answer (score 5):

I also got this issue in my magento 2.3.5-p1, based on the answer from this link :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Order-Email-not-showing-itemized-list-Magento-2-3-4/td-p/432836

just edit the column `is_legacy` value in the `email_template` table from 0 to 1, then the order items now will be displayed on the email. I've followed this way, and this is solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

i also got the same issue this is the final sollution
I confirm, this happens also in 2.3.5-p1

The solution set in db table: email_template column is_legacy = 1

set is_legacy = 1 in desired template and it will start working like miracle
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add below code inside success.phtml file,and you can fetch required data using below code,

```
<?php $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
      echo "<pre>";print_r($orderData->getData());   //Order_data
     //echo $orderData->getData('shipping_description'); //shipping_description
?>
```

Comment: Using object manager in the file directly is not a good approach.

Comment: That is not working for me, any solutions?

Comment: It means you have error in your collection. @DennyDanu

Comment: yes, we can not recommend to use object manager directly @Sumit

Comment: Have you found any solution